# Проблема с обработкой события WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

Сделал небольшую тестовую форму. При нажатии на **`<Canvas Name="BallsCentralStage" MouseDown="MouseDownHandler">`** должно генерироватся MouseDown event. На это событие повесил обработчик **MouseDownHandler**, который находится в класе MainWindow (тоесть, в главном окне). Как, все-таки, при нажатии на canvas обработать событие ?

```
<Window x:Class="PhysicsOfBalls.MainWindow">

    <DockPanel Name="MainDockPanel" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">

        <TabControl Name="MainTabControl">

            <TabItem Header="Settings" Name="SettingsTab"></TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Stage" Name="CanvasTab">
                <Canvas Name="BallsCentralStage" MouseDown="MouseDownHandler" Width="654" />
            </TabItem>

        </TabControl>

    </DockPanel>

</Window>
```

Comment: А в чём конкретно проблема? Покамест вы вроде бы всё делаете правильно.

Comment: обработчик должен прорисовывать обьект на канвас, но этого не происходит. Ставил breakpoint на обработчик - не вызывается. Работает только если повесить строчку MouseDown="MouseDownHandler" на каждый родительский тег, но это не совсем то, что нужно.

Comment: @nullptr: а, понял, смотрите ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте установить фон, хоть транспарентный:

```
<Canvas Name="BallsCentralStage" MouseDown="MouseDownHandler" Width="654"
        Background="Transparent" />
```

Многие элементы без фона «прозрачны» для кликов и других мышиных событий.

Comment: Работает! Спасибо! Несколько часов убил на эту ошибку, а тут оказывается всё просто )

Comment: @nullptr: Пожалуйста!